# How to calculate cumulative sum in python using pandas of all the columns except the first one that contain names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, cumsum

Here's the data in csv format:

```
Name 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020
Jack   1   15   25    3    5   11   5    8    3
Jill   5   10   32    5    5   14   6    8    7
```

I don't want Name column to be include as it gives an error.

I tried

```
df.cumsum()
```

Comment: `df.iloc[:,1:].cumsum()`

Comment: How can I join that first column back after calculating cumulative sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `set_index` and `reset_index` to keep the name column:

```
df.set_index('Name').cumsum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Name  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017  2018  2019  2020
0  Jack     1    15    25     3     5    11     5     8     3
1  Jill     6    25    57     8    10    25    11    16    10
```